# HTML version of LibGDX game doesn't show any logging

Tags: gwt, libgdx

I am having trouble getting a html version of my programme to appear.
I am using LibGDX 1.3.1 and running in Java it works fine.

I uploaded the game here:

http://www.darkflame.co.uk/MeshExplorer/index.html

The libgdx loading bar appears and finishes - and in Chromes network tag I can see assets loading.
However, nothing appears other then the rectangle of the expected game size.

Most confusingly for me though, I dont see any crashes or logs from my code.
That is, there is nothing after "SoundManager 2 loaded (OK) "

Given that the first lines of my main core class are:

```
   game=this;
   font = new BitmapFont();
   batch = new SpriteBatch();

   Gdx.app.log(logstag, "loading..");
```

I expected at least to see "loading.."

I even added some gwt logs to html launcher

```
 public class HtmlLauncher extends GwtApplication {
   static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger("HtmlLauncher");

    @Override
    public GwtApplicationConfiguration getConfig () {
       Log.info("GwtApplicationConfiguration");
      System.out.print("GwtApplicationConfiguration");
            return new GwtApplicationConfiguration(640, 480);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationListener getApplicationListener () {
          Log.info("test, returning class ME() ");
          System.out.print("test, returning class ME() ");
            return new ME();
    }

}
```

again, nothing.

I am at a lose how to disorganize this problem further.
It just seems like libgdx isn't even attempting to run my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default logging level in the html target is `LOG_ERROR`. You would not see any `Gdx.app.log` messages unless you set the logging level to `LOG_INFO`.

Calling `Gdx.app.setLogLevel(LOG_INFO)` in your `getConfig` or `getApplicationListener` methods should do the trick.

Comment: Placing that in the htmlauncher classes makes it crash on launch with:
"Cannot set property 'n' of undefined"
 
However, putting it in the core class in onCreate works and the logs following it show up.
I am puzzled, however, why the regular log statements I tried (System.out.print and Log.info) didnt result in output to the normal javascript console - which I prefer as I can actually select and copy stuff from it. GDXs logbox seems to block selections being made.

Comment: GWT doesn't translate `System.out.println` or `Logger` calls to `console.log` calls.

Comment: `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Name");`
`logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "this message should get logged");`

Works just fine in GWT - thats what I normally use and is being used here. Pretty sure its just java.util.logging emulated.

Comment: LibGDX makes no modification to Logger, so I couldn't tell you why it isn't working if it normally does for you.

Comment: ah, I found my mistake.
I needed to set it to inherit logger in the gwt.xml. Even though its emulated it wont respond correctly to levels set without that 
[DevGuideLogging](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Super_Simple_Recipe_for_Adding_Logging)